# Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

Tags: next.js, sanity

i am trying to connect the sanity backend to my nextjs front end project, although I have my id and token in my client.js file but I still face this error: Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

```js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';
export  const client = sanityClient ({
    projectID: '****',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-03-10',
    useCdn: true,
    token: NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_token
});
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I really appreciate it if somebody helps me find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, so change `projectID` to `projectId` (notice the lowercase `d`) in your Sanity `client`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the projectID key with projectId.

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';
export  const client = sanityClient ({
 projectId: '****',
 dataset: 'production',
 apiVersion: '2022-03-10',
 useCdn: true,
 token: NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_token
});
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```